# Getting magento custom product options on the SAME line as normal attributes Invoice / Email PDF

Tags: magento, pdf-generation, zend-pdf

I found a similar question regarding my issue here: [Magento PDF Invoices - how do I get custom product options to be on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397208/magento-pdf-invoices-how-do-i-get-custom-product-options-to-be-on-one-line/10191038#10191038)

But it's unfortunately not exactly what I am looking for. So my question is the following; How do I get the "attributes_info", configurable option variable to be on the SAME line as the other attributes. Like the name, Qty, Price etc.

I think I am pretty close, but I am not sure if its in the getItemOptions function or that its a nested array where the first value is empty.

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/0z1y2f0G070P172q2B1S